# Prove that, if $a>c$ and $b>d$, thus $ab>cd$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I would like to ask you a question: how could I prove that, if $a>c$ and $b>d$, thus $ab>cd$?

Thank you for help.

P.s. I forgot to tell you that $a>0, b>0, c>0, d>0.$

Comment: You have to watch out for signs.  $-1>-2$ but $(-1)^2<(-2)^2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer:)

Comment: Hi Roby, if a>0, b>0, c>0, d>0, a>c, b>d, hence: a>c --> ab> cb, c>d --> cb>db and then ab>cb>db but not >cd.

Comment: Sorry Roby, I did a mistake! You are right:)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all are positive 
$a\gt c$ and $b\gt d$

$ba\gt bc$ by multiplying the first inequality by $b$, and $bc\gt cd$ multiplying the second inequality by $c.$

Combining yields $ba\gt bc\gt cd$ therefore $ba\gt cd$.

Important this only works when we assume all $(a,b,c,d)$ to be greater than $0.$ Consider $-1\gt -2$ but $1\lt 2$. In general inequalities flip when you multiply by a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

product or sum of positive numbers is positive.

$$ ab-cd = (ab - ad) + (ad - cd) = a(b-d) +(a-c)d > 0.  $$

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R^+}$, then it can be seen $ab > bc >cd$

This holds as $ab>bc \Rightarrow b(a-c)>0$, which is true as $b>0$ and $a>c$.

Similarly, $bc>cd \Rightarrow c(b-d)>0$, which is true as $c>0$ and $b>d$.